Export file to csv/xlsx inc. name of the object and custom property description
I hope someone will be able to help me with the following question:
I could export my (.stl) file and open it in csv/xlsx and I obtained the data/information that I was expecting, except for the object name (e.g. shelve_001) and custom property description (e.g.X2-0502). I would like to have these fields next to my vertex in csv/xlsx, in order to make an unique relationship in Tableau (SKUs in this location). Unfortunatly, I only have the following information, therefore I can make this object in Tableau, but due to not having a unique description/name, I cannot link it properly. Could someone help me with this question? Thank you!

solid               
facet   normal  -6,52E-04   0   -1
    outer   loop        
    vertex  0.49031344  -0.015721008    0.017247617
    vertex  0.94772 -0.015721008    0.017247587
    vertex  0.94772 -0.51312757 0.017247587
    endloop         
endfacet                
facet   normal  -6,52E-04   0   -1
    outer   loop        
    vertex  0.49031344  -0.015721008    0.017247617
    vertex  0.94772 -0.51312757 0.017247587
    vertex  0.49031344  -0.51312757 0.017247617
    endloop         
endfacet                
facet   normal  0   -1  0
    outer   loop        
    vertex  0.49031347  -0.51312757 0.41724762
    vertex  0.49031344  -0.51312757 0.017247617
    vertex  0.94772 -0.51312757 0.017247587
    endloop         

